# How to find revision which create branch in SVN repository?

Tags: python, svn, logging, xml-parsing

From a given SVN repository, I'm trying to write a script to find the revisions which creates branches. In TortoiseSVN revision graph, you can easily spot them so I guess it's possible.

So far, I can almost do it by parsing the full verbose log in xml format(`svn log -v --xml`) and filtering the `logentry` nodes (Python with minidom module):

```
liste_revision = [item for item in doc.getElementsByTagName('logentry')
if (item.getElementsByTagName('path').length==1 and
item.getElementsByTagName('path')[0].getAttribute('kind')=="dir" and
item.getElementsByTagName('path')[0].getAttribute('action')=="A" and
"/branches/" in item.getElementsByTagName('path')[0].firstChild.nodeValue)]
```

I said almost because there's an unwanted item or two that still go through those filters. This algorithm is also quite heavy because I'm filtering the whole log.

So my questions are :

- Does it exist a svn log command that would filter directly ? I've heard of `svn log --stop-on-copy` but it looks like it works only for current branch.
- Do you think there's a better filter to use ? I've made this one from the examples in my repository.
- (subsidiary) am I right thinking that a branch creation implies a revision ?